# Big integer value does not display properly when importing

Tags: angularjs, excel, csv, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angular-ui-grid` and its export to .csv functionality. In a grid, one column is showing big decimal values such as `10012279001780`, `10020056601780`. These values display correctly on a web page. There is no filter applied on the column. When I export it to .csv and open in MS Excel, these values display as `1.00123E+13`, `1.00128E+13`.

I tried to apply below filter also:

```
HelperServices.filter('decimal', function () {
    return function (text) {
        return parseFloat(text).toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '');
    };
});
```

But still values are not coming properly in MS Excel. I've tried with `type:string` and `type:number` of a column as well. Even values are printed properly on `console` without any filter or any type applied.

How do I display big decimal values properly when exporting to .csv and opening in MS Excel?

Comment: @pnuts- changing type of cell in excel or selecting a text displays the correct value. But it requires user's interaction with excel. I want it to be displayed as same as it is in a grid on a webpage.

Comment: That's native excel functionality... try adding a `'` before exporting. `'10012279001780` forces excel to format as text.